# Python - Filtering out files by extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder that has two excel files (file extension .xls). I am trying to filter out only xls files from the folder as per the below code

```
filtered_files = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.xls")
```

Given below are the details of the folder

`folder_path` is the path for the folder. This folder has 2 xls files (`file1.xls` and `file2.xls`)

However when I print `filtered_files` it only returns one file (file2.xls) as this was the last file added to the folder and when I run the script again it detects the second file.

Comment: Please provide a larger snippet of code. What you have provided so far should return a list of paths.

Comment: try `os.listdir('folder_path')` and see if both file exists

Comment: I don't see any problem with the command that you have used. Same thing working fine for me ! If possible give your entire code!

Comment: Sounds like an order of operations issue, are you maybe running `glob` before both files are written?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this:

```
xls_files = [os.path.join(folder_path,x) for x in os.listdir(folder_path) if x.split('.')[-1] == "xls"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use glob for this kind of thing. I suspect the mistake you have made is with joining the path. The below code shows how to correctly join file/folder paths.

```
import glob
import os

folder_path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents"
filter_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "*.xls")
filtered_files = glob.glob(filter_path)

print(filtered_files)
```